# Dropdown button width css

Tags: html, css

First, the dropdown button works fine.
I need to change the width of those button and make it fit the window.
But once i resize the width of the button the error occur? can someone help?

**Code**

```css
.head{
    width:100%;
}

.head a {
    background-color:rgb(255,205,255);
    width:20%;
    padding: 15px 0px 15px 0px;
    float: left;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    border:1px solid pink;
}

.dropdown {
    float: left;
    width:19%;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
    background-color:rgb(255,205,255);    
    border:1px solid pink;
    border-right: none; 
    color: black;
    padding: 15px 0px 15px 0px;
    font-size: inherit;
    font-family: inherit;
    margin: 0;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 20px grey;
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    float: none;
    color: black;
    padding: 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.head a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color:rgb(255,182,193);
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color:rgb(255,182,193);
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

.head > a:not(:last-child){
    border-right: none; 
}

.dropdown-content a:not(:last-child){
    border-bottom: none; 
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="head">
        <a href="#home">Home</a>
        <a href="#news">Menu</a>
        <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="dropbtn">Orders 
                <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
            </button>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="#">Add</a>
                <a href="#">Update</a>
                <a href="#">Delete</a>
            </div>
        </div> 
        <a href="#news">Cart</a>
        <a href="#news">Logout</a>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `width: 100%` in this class `.dropdown-content a` (this is for dropdown width) and this class `.dropdown .dropbtn` (this is for button width)

[**JsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/v3x7gb60/5/)

Answer (score 0):

```css
.head{
width:100%;
}
.head a {
background-color:rgb(255,205,255);
width:20%;
padding: 15px 0px 15px 0px;
float: left;
color: black;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
border:1px solid pink;
}

.dropdown {
float: left;
width:19%;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
background-color:rgb(255,205,255);    
border:1px solid pink;
border-right: none; 
color: black;
padding: 15px 0px 15px 0px;
font-size: inherit;
font-family: inherit;
margin: 0;
width:100%
}


.dropdown-content {
display: none;
box-shadow: 5px 5px 20px grey;
z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {

    float: none;
    width: 100%;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.head a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
background-color:rgb(255,182,193);
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
background-color:rgb(255,182,193);
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
display: block;
}

.head > a:not(:last-child){
border-right: none; 
}

.dropdown-content a:not(:last-child){
border-bottom: none; 
}
```

```html
<div class="head">
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">Menu</a>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Orders 
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Add</a>
      <a href="#">Update</a>
      <a href="#">Delete</a>
    </div>
  </div> 
  <a href="#news">Cart</a>
  <a href="#news">Logout</a>
</div>
```